# map.delete(key) during map.forEach

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, ecmascript-6

Typically, you cannot safely delete items from an list while you're looping through that list. Does this concept remain true for ES6 Maps?

I tried this simple test without exceptions:

```js
var map = new Map([['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]);
    map.forEach((value,key,map)=>
    {
          map.delete(key);
          let str = `["${key}",${value}] was deleted. `;
          str += `map.size = ${map.size}`;
          console.log(str);
    });
```

It seems ok.

**Update:** I just read this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach#Description) from Mozilla. It is certainly doable. I'd be interested in any performance benchmarks comparing this method of deletion with other methods (on larger datasets).

Comment: You can, it's safe, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940216/es6-is-it-dangerous-to-delete-elements-from-set-map-during-set-map-iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I guess you're right. I am not quite familiar with the ES6 Maps, but had done a bit of research and found this blog a bit helpful where it explains about the MAPS:

https://hackernoon.com/what-you-should-know-about-es6-maps-dc66af6b9a1e

Here you will get the deleting mechanism explanation too:
Something like this:

```
var m = new Map()
m.set('a', 1)
m.set('b', 2)
m.delete('a'); // true
m.delete('c'); // false (key was not there to delete)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Why? If you are working with the same instance, actually you can delete. It has functions which are used for deleting an item, so you can delete.

But from the side of **Optimization** don't delete any item from the `Map` or `array`. Javascript engines have optimizations based on the shape of the object. If it is the same over some reference to that object, it would be optimized. Instead of this, create a new object from the filtered values of the current object.

```js
var map =  new Map([['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]);
map.forEach((value,key,map)=>
{
      map.delete(key);
});

console.log(map);
```

There are some languages ( C# ), that you can't remove items from the `IEnumerable` in the `for each loop`, because it works another way under the hood, actually it gives you only read and update access, not delete.

Comment: Another View from Java Perspective : Deleting Entries in Map in Java will iterating will create an Error .. May be he is thinking on those lines

Comment: *"Javascript engines have optimizations based on the shape of the object."* - this is for object properties. Map entries are not properties of the Map object; you access them via `map.get('a')`, not `map.a`.