# How do I delete data from the local storage?

Tags: javascript

I have two input fieds where i get title and notes. They are are stored in an array which i iterate over to display on the web browser. Now, when I delete a note, the deleted note is stored in another array which i loop over to display as trash. All data are stored in the localstorage.

```
function displayTrash() {
  document.getElementById('mynotes').innerHTML = '';
  let content = document.getElementById('mynotes');
  let container = document.getElementById('c-note');
  let icon = document.getElementById('icon1');
  container.classList.add('none');
  if (deletedTitle.length === 0 && deletedText.length === 0) {
    content.innerHTML += `<div class="empty-notes"><h1>Trash is empty !!</h1></div>`;
    return;
  }
  let trashTitle = localStorage.getItem('dtitle');
  let trashNote = localStorage.getItem('dnote');

  if (trashTitle && trashNote) {
    trashTitle = JSON.parse(trashTitle);
    trashNote = JSON.parse(trashNote);
    for (let i = 0; i < trashTitle.length; i++) {
      const notesTitle = trashTitle[i];
      const notesBody = trashNote[i];

      content.innerHTML += /*html*/ `

            <div class="note">
                  <h4>${notesTitle}</h4>
                 <div class="note-title">
                <p class="text">${notesBody}</p>
                <i class="uil uil-trash-alt trash" onclick="deleteTrash(${i})"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }
  }
}




function save() {
  let titleAsText = JSON.stringify(noteTitle);
  let noteAsText = JSON.stringify(noteText);
  let deletedTitleAsText = JSON.stringify(deletedTitle);
  let deletedNoteText = JSON.stringify(deletedText);
  localStorage.setItem('title', titleAsText);
  localStorage.setItem('note', noteAsText);
  localStorage.setItem('dtitle', deletedTitleAsText);
  localStorage.setItem('dnote', deletedNoteText);
}

function getItem() {
  let titleAsText = localStorage.getItem('title');
  let noteAsText = localStorage.getItem('note');
  let deletedNoteText = localStorage.getItem('dtitle');
  let deletedTitleAsText = localStorage.getItem('dnote');

  if (titleAsText && noteAsText) {
    noteTitle = JSON.parse(titleAsText);
    noteText = JSON.parse(noteAsText);
  }
  if (deletedNoteText && deletedTitleAsText) {
    deletedText = JSON.parse(deletedNoteText);
    deletedTitle = JSON.parse(deletedTitleAsText);
  }
}
```

to delete a note on the browser, I wrote the following code:

```
function deleteNotes(i) {
  let trashTitle = noteTitle.splice(i, 1);
  let trashNote = noteText.splice(i, 1);
  deletedTitle.push(trashTitle);
  deletedText.push(trashNote);
  displayNotes();
  save();
}
```

The code above works.

but to delete note in the trash, iwrote the following code:

```
function deleteTrash(i) {
  let trashTitle = deletedTitle.splice(i, 1);
  let trashNote = deletedText.splice(i, 1);
  displayTrash();
}
```

That didn't work. I want to be able to delete each note in the trash and thereby removing it from the localstorage.

Comment: You can't use the original array indexes when you delete notes or trash. After you delete a note, all the following array indexes shift down. And the array indexes in the `trash` arrays aren't related to the original indexes at all.

Comment: You should use arrays of objects, and delete items by a unique ID property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When removing an item from an array, you end up changing the index of all items after that removal.

One way to address this is to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), instead of an Array. With maps, you can [safely delete items while looping through the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149010/map-deletekey-during-map-foreach).

```
// Initialize Maps
let notesMap = new Map();
let deletedNotesMap = new Map();

// Save to LocalStorage
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(Array.from(notesMap)));
  localStorage.setItem('deletedNotes', JSON.stringify(Array.from(deletedNotesMap)));
}

// Load from LocalStorage
function load() {
  const savedNotes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
  const savedDeletedNotes = localStorage.getItem('deletedNotes');
  if (savedNotes) notesMap = new Map(JSON.parse(savedNotes));
  if (savedDeletedNotes) deletedNotesMap = new Map(JSON.parse(savedDeletedNotes));
}

// Delete Note
function deleteNote(id) {
  const noteToDelete = notesMap.get(id);
  deletedNotesMap.set(id, noteToDelete);
  notesMap.delete(id);
  save();
}

// Delete from Trash
function deleteTrash(id) {
  deletedNotesMap.delete(id);
  save();
}

// Display Notes and Trash
function displayNotes() {
  notesMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    // Display the notes
  });
}

function displayTrash() {
  deletedNotesMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    // Display the trash
  });
}
```