# Higher perf - Map.prototype.forEach or for..of?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, es6-map

Say I have:

```
const m = new Map();
```

is there a performance difference between:

```
for(let v of m){

}
```

vs.

```
m.forEach(v => {});
```

I assume `Map.protoype.forEach` uses an iterator just like for..of? I read here that's it safe to delete keys from the map during iteration using for..of, see: [ES6: Is it dangerous to delete elements from Set/Map during Set/Map iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940216/es6-is-it-dangerous-to-delete-elements-from-set-map-during-set-map-iteration)

and I am wondering if it's safe to delete keys from the map with a `Map.prototype.forEach` loop also.

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Per [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.foreach): *Keys that are deleted after the call to forEach begins and before being visited are not visited unless the key is added again before the forEach call completes.*

Comment: @Li357 post the answer!

Comment: Of course, it's safe to delete elements with forEach, it would be a fatal flaw otherwise. As for performance, you can try them yourself on jsperf, that's what you ask other users to do for you. I'd expect both of them to be very fast. for..of has more potential to be optimized in JS engines because it doesn't involve a function (for..of recently outperformed array forEach in V8, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424599/3731501 ).

Comment: As for performance, jsPerf it: https://jsperf.com/for-of-vs-foreach-map/1

Comment: I don't get points for doing it myself, but you get points for posting an answer lol, and we share the knowledge by posting on a public forum..

Comment: wow so forEach is about 50% faster, I wonder why

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Quality self-answers are encouraged on SO, you could try to get points from it if that's your intention. It isn't necessarily faster. It may depend on map size as well, apart from possible difference between engines. That's why 'vs' questions are often inappropriate.

Comment: Looks like the classic `for` loop is the fastest. I'm a huge fan of `reduce` because you get a `map` and `filter` in the same function, plus you can return more types than just an array. https://jsperf.com/filter-map-vs-reduce/4

Comment: @MaxBaldwin no, `Map.prototype.forEach` was more performant than the  `for..of` loop AFAICT. Possibly because the former does no use iterators? not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little benchmark with the following code on node.js 8.11

```
const Benchmark = require('benchmark');
const suite = new Benchmark.Suite();

suite
  .add('for of', function () {
    const m = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      m.set(`key${i}`, i);
    }

    for (let v of m) {
      m.delete(v);
    }
  })
  .add('forEach', function () {
    const m = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      m.set(`key${i}`, i);
    }

    m.forEach(v => {
      m.delete(v);
    })
  })
  .on('cycle', function (event) {
    console.log(String(event.target));
  })
  .on('complete', function () {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
  })
  // run async
  .run({ 'async': true });
```

And the result was pretty interesting:

```
for of x 88,105 ops/sec ±0.36% (89 runs sampled)
forEach x 81,532 ops/sec ±0.55% (90 runs sampled)
Fastest is for of
```

Comment: Doesn't that only test iteration on empty maps (after the first run)?

Comment: I would expect that `new Map()`, `set` and `delete` are much more costly than iteration. You can be sure that `for` loop contributes, too. For more meaningful results, try noop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I was also interested in this and created a [JSPerf benchmark](https://jsperf.com/map-for-of-vs-foreach) that performs a simple raw iteration over a map but doesn't do anything with the entries themselves.

A for-of loop like the following:

```
for (let entry of testMap) ...
```

**consistently performs about 15-20% faster** in chrome when it comes to just iterating over the entire thing, compared to forEach.

If you need better readability, array destructuring in the loop expression itself is the slowest, it actually performs on the level of forEach:

```
for (let [key, value] of testMap) ...
```

Using local variables is half-way between the two, faster than array destructuring but slower than the raw loop:

```
for (let entry of testMap) {
    let key = entry[0];
    let value = entry[1];
}
```

Additionally, for-of loops also have the added benefit of not requiring the creation of a function, which means less potential garbage generated when the `forEach` is called with an anonymous function expression created with each call.